# Quasars with differing emission / absorption redshifts

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, gravitational-redshift

I was reading this (perhaps offbeat) "anti-big-bang" article,

http://www.newtonphysics.on.ca/hubble/

and the author comments "a recent catalog of objects having very large redshifts shows that among 109 quasi-stellar objects for which both absorption and emission lines could be measured, the value of the absorption redshift of a given object is always different from the one measured in emission for the same object."

So,

1. I had trouble Googling this. What is a particularly good "example object" of this phenomenon (if any), perhaps where I can see the issues arising discussed?
2. Is there a prosaic or generally accepted "conventional" explanation?

---

BTW I've just realised the article is perhaps from 1988 (it's somewhat confusingly also dated 2012) - so this may be completely out of date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a quick look at the paper - it's mostly nonsense. The intrinsic light from a quasar is completely dominated by its emission line spectrum and a mostly featureless continuum. The observed wavelength of the *emission* lines compared to the rest wavelength give the true redshift of the quasar.

Absorption lines in quasar spectra are predominantly due to *foreground* gas clouds at lower redshifts than the more distant quasar source. Therefore the absorption lines do evidence a lower redshift, but that's because they are due to gas that is unassociated with the quasar.

Here's a picture from a [Hamburg Sternwarte](http://www.hs.uni-hamburg.de/EN/For/Exg/Igm/index.html) description of these absorption lines, that illustrates the situation. Absorption lines are formed due to absorption of the quasar continuum by gas clouds (or maybe even much fainter normal galaxies) A, B and C, which are at progressively lower redshifts (often multiple absorption systems can be found and can be used not only to place the distance of the intervening cloud/galaxy but also say something about its chemical composition). Spectrum D shows how the measured spectrum at the telescope will contain a highly redshifted quasar's light with superimposed absorption bands due to the lower redshift clouds.

[image: The formation of absorption lines in quasar spectra]

Comment: Outstanding!  To be clear, with "astronomical spectroscopy", in general, are you measuring the light (etc) **coming off** objects, or light that has happened to **travel through** something (such as a gas) i.e. as in the image A B C.  Or indeed, "both of those"?

Comment: Heh someone seemed to knock off that image on the wiki page .. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_spectroscopy

Comment: @Joe - you are talking about "radiative transfer". Absorption lines appear due to light travelling through something else. In a star of course, the something else is the star's own atmosphere. Here, the gas clouds do not have anything to do with the quasar.

Comment: Ahh!  So if we look at Star ABC (a simple nearby star with nothing in between), at the absorption lines .. we're looking at the absorption by **the star's atmosphere**.  Brilliant.

Comment: In the situation in the diagram.  This may be naive but couldn't you just go off center, and see if the "ABC" remain, but the quasar's features would disappear? Further reinforcing that ABC are, indeed, just features near us?  (Or, is everything involved "too small" to be able to nudge to one side?  ie ABC are just as apparently small as the distant target.)

Comment: The diagram is not to scale! The clouds and quasars are hundreds of millions, if not billions of light years away and the quasar is effectively a point of light.

Comment: Right, I assumed that.  Can you go "off axis" to check that the signature from ABC remains, but the signature from the quasar disappears?  Or is that naive.

Comment: But then you have no background illuminating continuum upon which to see the absorption lines. One *can* try and detect these galaxies using alternative diagnostics though - such as 21cm radiation. See for example http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2009MNRAS.396..385K

Comment: (Quasars are damn convenient if you happen to want to study the galaxies / gas blobs at ABC !)

Comment: Well gas blobs appear remarkably common and some transitions, like Lyman alpha can produce absorption with relatively little gas in the way. Many high redshift quasars have multiple absorption line systems.

Comment: Got it cheers..